# should do vs must do

Tags: british-english

The other day, to me great surprise I've learnt from an English native speaker that one must avoid using **must** in sentences and use **should** instead which did strike me as odd indeed because I do constantly hear native English speakers say things like:

- Alright, I **must** go now.
- You **must** have done this a week ago.
- I'm quite impressed, I **must** say.

I do know the difference between the two but still, I fail to understand why some people say that ***must*** must not be used.

Any valid reasons behind that?

Comment: I think you **must** have misunderstood! Maybe the person meant to advise against using it when giving instructions? If you tell someone they **must** do something, it sounds like a command, but telling them they **should** do it makes it more of a polite request or suggestion.